# Matrix endomorphism rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $(A, B) \in M_n(\mathbb{C})^2, u \in L(M_n(\mathbb{C})) \text{
> > s.t. } \forall M \in M_n(\mathbb{C}), \text{ } u(M)=AMB$.
>
> 1) Find $\det(u)$
>
> 2) Find $\mathrm{rk}(u)$

1) $\det(u) = \det(A)^n\det(B)^n$.

2) I said $u = u_A \circ u_B$ where $u_A(M)=AM$ and $u_B(M) = MB$, and :
$$\mathrm{rk}(u_A) = n \cdot \mathrm{rk}(A)\text{, } \mathrm{rk}(u_B) = n \cdot \mathrm{rk}(B)$$
However, it only means that $\mathrm{rk}(u) \leq \min(\mathrm{rk}(u_A), \mathrm{rk}(u_B))$ and doesn't allow me to find $\mathrm{rk}(u)$

What could I use ? (just tips please, or use "spoiler" if you post complete answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints.**

1. Let $\{Ax_1, Ax_2, \ldots, Ax_r\}$ be a basis of the column space of $A$, and $\{x_{r+1},\ldots,x_n\}$ be a basis of the null space of $A$.
2. Similarly, let $\{B^Ty_1, B^Ty_2, \ldots, B^Ty_k\}$ be a basis of the column space of $B^T$, and $\{y_{k+1},\ldots,y_n\}$ be a basis of the null space of $B^T$.
3. Show that the image of $u$ is spanned by $\{Ax_iy_j^TB: 1\le i\le r,\ 1\le j\le k\}$. Explain why this is a linearly independent set of matrices.
4. Now what is the rank of $u$?

Comment: Thank you ! Is it $\mathrm{rk}(A)\mathrm{rk}(B)$ or did I do something wrong ?

Comment: @servabat Yes, it's the product of the two ranks.